# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/EncryptedDocumentException

Tags: java, tomcat, apache-poi

I m building a web app and using apache poi for working on excel sheets. When I start the server I get the following exception. Thing is it used to work fine until i tried to build it and deploy in on heroku (but might be irrelevant).
Anybody has an idea??

```
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 15, 2016 8:28:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
Apr 15, 2016 8:28:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.engine.OnStartup
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/EncryptedDocumentException
    at org.engine.OnStartup.contextInitialized(OnStartup.java:16)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 10 more
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>psilos-toy</groupId>
<artifactId>psilos-toy</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.httpcache4j.resolvers</groupId>
        <artifactId>resolvers-net-urlconnection</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-M6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache POI,for handling Excel Files -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- jersey -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and my web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
  <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
                </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>org.endpoints</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.engine.OnStartup</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Are all of the dependencies listed turning up in your war file? An `unzip -l build.war | grep jar` ought to show

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it was working on a Tomcat setup that had poi classes available on the `classpath`. In the new Heroku setup, perhaps you don't have those classes available with Tomcat 7 (I haven't thoroughly checked if poi classes come bundled with Tomcat 7).

The easiest thing you can do is to build a self-contained app by bundling the poi classes along with your app. This increase your app's size, but you get to control the poi library version. Of course, you can always copy the libraries to a defined folders (where you know Tomcat loads the classes from). See maven-shade-plugin for details.

Comment: Shouldn't the war contain these dependencies? I mean none of his depenced are scope `provided`

Comment: @panipsilos, can you please check the poi jar file for EncryptedDocumentException class file in org.apache.poi package.
You will get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError whenever JVM doesn't find the class file

Comment: @SGM1, "provided: This scope indicates that dependency is to be provided by JDK or web-Server/Container at runtime" -- I don't think that's the case here. And which "war" are you referring to?

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your comments. So what I did eventually is to create a new project and copy my source code there. That solved my problem. I think I messed it up with the pom.xml and with the process of trying to build my project with maven, but I cannot tell in which way or what went wrong.

Comment: Could it be that m2e plugin caused the problem? Cause now, when I m updating the maven project, I get a "Unable to configure <project_name>", "An exception stack trace is not available.", in the "org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender" plugin.